# Two types of user accounts with django user accounts

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a web application and I'd like to split the sign-up/registration process between

A. Individuals

and

B. Employers

where each sign-up form contains similar elements but are also different.

What's the best approach to doing this? Inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Concentrating only on forms + views section ( assuming you are done with the models).

Since all the fields are same for both the entities. You can differentiate when you create the object of the signup form in views method.

```
def employer_signup(request):
    form = CommonSignupForm(request.Post or None)
    # do something with it

def individual_signup(request):
    form = CommonSignupForm(request.Post or None)
    # do something else with it
```

Now, i assume, max you have to do in this is to set user_type of the user signing up. Following code should be in each method.

```
user = form.save(commit=false)
user.user_type = 'E'  # depends what tags you are using
user.save()
```